# react native chrome custom tabs given error

Tags: react-native, chrome-custom-tabs

I have installed chrome custom tabs in react native app using this "npm install --save react-native-chrome-custom-tabs". I have made all changes as mentioned in the github.com (https://github.com/dstaley/react-native-chrome-custom-tabs) but its not working its given an error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'D.launchCustomTab')
```

I have added in app android/settings.gradle:-

```
include ':ReactNativeChromeCustomTabs', ':app'
project(':ReactNativeChromeCustomTabs').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-chrome-custom-tabs/android')
```

Added

```
compile project(':ReactNativeChromeCustomTabs')
```

to dependencies in android/app/build.gradle

in app/src/main/java/com/animatedapp/MainActivity.java file its already have code :

package com.animatedapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "AnimatedApp";
    }
}
```

I don't know where to add code that is given in the github.com

```
import com.dstaley.ReactNativeChromeCustomTabs.ChromeCustomTabsPackage; // <-- Import

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {

    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .addPackage(new ChromeCustomTabsPackage(this))          // <-- Register
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();

        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "DemoReactNativeCustomTabs", null);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }
```

how can i install this properly ??

Comment: I am also stuck at this. did you able to resolve it? Is there any other alternative that does the same job?